# String.Split syntax wrong

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

The IDE tells me that my syntax is wrong

```
 Dim uString As String ="SomeString"
 Dim myDelims() As String = New String() {  uSplitBy  })
 Dim sVec() As String = s.Split(myDelims, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

I don't see where I went wrong. Does anybody see it?
Thak you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unnecessary `)` at the end of the second line.